# Swift return value in setter

Tags: swift, swift3, return-value, getter-setter

I need to return a string from a setter, How can I do that? Here is the code:

```
func example()->String{ 
    var _a = 5
    var a: Int{
        set(newValue){
            _a = newValue
            if _a < 0{
                //return a string here!!
            }
        }get{
            return _a
        }
    }
    a = 0
}
```

Comment: setter Only set value no return. But you can use  variable in your `example` method

Comment: Logically speaking, you can't *return* a value in *setter*...

Comment: why you wanna return any value from set? what's the use of it?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do that unfortunately, but it will be quite confusing if you *could* do that anyway.

We all know that closures are first class citizens in Swift and that closures can be nested. What you are doing here is putting a closure inside another closure and trying to return a value from the inner closure. However, even if closures can be nested, two different closures are two different closures. Think of nested closures as non-nested closures. Sure you can use values from the outer closure in the inner closure:

```
func a(x: Int) {
     func b() {
         // use x here
     }
}
```

But that's something you can do with 2 non-nested closures as well. What you are trying to do is to make the outer closure return by returning a value from the inner closure:

```
func a() -> String {
    func b() {
        return ""
    }

    b()
}
```

This is simply not possible with 2 non-nested closures:

```
func a() -> String {
    b()
}

func b() {
    return ""
}
```

And anyway, it will be very hard to understand your code if you really *could* do this. As a reader of your code, people would expect a return statement that states what value to return exactly. They do not expect a

```
a = 0
```

that returns stuff. They would have to look into the setter of `a` in order to know what value the closure will return. That is a lot of looking up and down in the code, which is very inconvenient.